# New window can't resize in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, resize, window

When I click a link new `window` will open. But I can't `resize`(also `maximize`) the browser `window` in **IE**.

But I can `resize` and `maximize`  the `window` if the browser is **chrome** or **firefox** etc.

My code is:

```
$("#linkId").click(function(){
 //window.open('../blocks/eparticipation/view.php?cId='+courseId, 'chatWindow', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=1000,height=500'); 
window.open('../blocks/eparticipation/eparticipation_home.php?cId='+courseId, 'chatWindow', 'location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1, width=1000,height=500'); 
return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to add

```
resizable=yes
```

to parameters. This is a special property for IE.